# How can I launch Cassini Web Server from a command line or batch file?

Tags: asp.net, command-line, webserver, cassini

Is there anyways to launch Cassini web server from a command line?   The exe appears to be in this path, C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0

I try to use the suggested parameters but it doesn't seem to work.  Does anyone know of, or have a script that can accomplish this?

Thanks for any help or tips,
Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Example:

```
taskkill /F /IM WebDev.WebServer.exe

START /D “C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\9.0\” /B WebDev.WebServer.EXE /port:5002 /path:”d:\Projects\myproject\project.service” /vpath:”/Project.Service”
```

Check this out:

[Starting Cassini manually](http://rogerpence.com/blog/index.php/archives/245)

Answer (score 0):

Consider also using [UWS Pro](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst633_Welcome-to-UltiDev-Web-Server-Pro.aspx). It's a free web server that's fairly advanced and can be [started from the command line to debug](http://ultidev.com/Forums/yaf_postst661_Debugging-your-web-app-with-UWS--or-just-hosting-the-app-from-command-line.aspx) ASP.NET applications from .NET 1.1 to 4. 
[image: Interactive (non-service) based hosting of web applications under UltiDev Web Server Pro]